# What are mv, fd, aq, vq, sq and f in a video stream?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am playing video streams using RTSP over TCP using FFPLAY and it plays fine when the vq value increases, but stops after 5-6 seconds when only the value before M-V increases.

```
nan M-V:    nan fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
......
......

Duration: N/A, start: 2.133467, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x1024, 15 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x7fd9502403c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
  "76.81" M-V: -5.409 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=2/2 `
```

Can someone please explain what these M-V, fd, aq, vq, f are, as well as the value before M-V ("76.81")?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question and by looking in `ffplay` source found this:

```
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO,
               "%7.2f %s:%7.3f fd=%4d aq=%5dKB vq=%5dKB sq=%5dB f=%"PRId64"/%"PRId64"   \r",
               get_master_clock(is),
               (is->audio_st && is->video_st) ? "A-V" : (is->video_st ? "M-V" : (is->audio_st ? "M-A" : "   ")),
               av_diff,
               is->frame_drops_early + is->frame_drops_late,
               aqsize / 1024,
               vqsize / 1024,
               sqsize,
               is->video_st ? is->viddec.avctx->pts_correction_num_faulty_dts : 0,
               is->video_st ? is->viddec.avctx->pts_correction_num_faulty_pts : 0)
```

Playing a sample video got a sample of the output:

`7.11 A-V:  0.003 fd=   1 aq=   21KB vq=  321KB sq=    0B f=0/0`

`7.11 (master clock)` is the time from start of the stream/video

`A-V (avdiff)` Difference between audio and video timestamps

`fd` Number of frames dropped

`aq` size of audio frame

`vq` size of video frame

`sq` size of subtitle frame

`f` Timestamp error correction rate (Not 100% sure)

`M-V`, `M-A` means video stream only, audio stream only respectively.

Comment: They should certainly have mentioned this in their manual `man ffplay`.

Comment: @neverMind9 You'll be surprised how many features aren't documented in FFmpeg and can only be known by reading the code

Answer (score 9):

I want to clarify that `aq, vq` are "audio queue size" and "video queue size" respectively, not "size of audio/video frame" as in Marware answer.

Sorry for posting an incomplete answer but this thread is #1 result in google search for `ffmpeg vq` and I hope that my clarification will be helpful for those who will happen to be here looking for what `vq` means.

Here's some practical (but niche) example of what `vq` (video queue size) means in a practical sense.

Let's say you are using ffplay to show a video from a security camera. In this particular case that `vq` number (together with a camera stream bandwidth) will define a delay from the 'real-time' to the picture seen in ffplay.

For example, if a security camera delivers a high-quality 10Mbps stream and `vq` is somewhere around 300K, then the latency/delay about 1/4 of a second. A quarter of a second delay is almost unnoticeable.

`delay (seconds) = vq_number * 8 * 1024 / video_stream_bits_per_second`

Now if the camera streams at 2Mbps and `vq` is 1000K (not uncommon) the latency (delay) is about four seconds. That means what you see in ffplay right now was happening four seconds ago.

In any other case - the more `vq`, the better. Larger `vq` means there's enough data queued (buffered) for smooth video playback.